# Does State of Decay's DLC change the base game

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-breakdown, state-of-decay-lifeline

Are the new features added in the DLC added into the base game as well, or does the base game remain unchanged?

I know the 1st DLC is a non-story based DLC and the 2nd one is from the Army's perspective, but are the new weapons or skills also added into the base game or does this remain unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only substantial thing changed in the base game is that you can load rucksacks and items onto vehicles. New weapons, characters, items, skills, etc are exclusive to the DLCs only.